# Can't access to my war file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, ear

I have an application which is a ear file which contains war and some jar file. I want to access my war's web-inf folder using java code. I tried a lot but could not found anything that can help me to access my war file.

I extracted my ear file in folder structure according to jboss forums but still cant access web-inf folder.

i tried this code but it is returning the jboss bin folder not deployment folder

```
org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile vFile = org.jboss.vfs.VFS.getChild("WEB-INF/config/custom.xml");
    org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile vFile1 = org.jboss.vfs.VFS.getRootVirtualFile();
```

I also tried using JNDI but could not solve the main problem.

```
InitialContext ic;
try {
    ic = new InitialContext();
    String moduleName = (String) ic.lookup("java:module/MyModule");
    String appName = (String) ic.lookup("java:app/devcenter");
    System.out.println("app name is : " + appName);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone help me? How can I access my WEB-INF folder so that I can change my xml content at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't. An EAR is an archive which means you'd have to know the path, uncompress the archive (or at least the file from the archive), change it and compress the archive again. This would likely require or trigger (can't recall if it happens automatically) a redeploy.

If you have a file you're using for configuration I would suggest you store it in a known path you add to the [paths](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/General+configuration+concepts#Generalconfigurationconcepts-Paths) in the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it that way. What you can do is include that in your build path. Then you can access it like you would access any resource files. So copy them over to a folder inside your source folder. For example - `src\main\resources\config\custom.xml`. Your java classes will be inside `src\main\java\` and your resource files will be there.